# Adjectival clauses with time subordinating conjunctions (before)

Tags: adjectivals

I know that we can use "before" (which is a time subordinating conjunction) for an adjectival clause.

For example:

> All the years **before Jesus' birth** receive the label B.C.

I would like somebody to confirm that when using an adjectival clause with "before",  we cannot **describe things other than time**.

This would not make sense, for example:

> **The countries before Jesus' birth** did not have Christianity.

Comment: You have a few errors: firstly, clauses are not adjectives; they functions as either modifiers or complements. "Before" is a preposition, so "before Jesus' birth" is a PP (preposition phrase) modifying "years".  Yes, In examples like yours, "before" normally occurs in temporal PPs.

Comment: Adverbial / adjectival ***before Jesus' birth*** can *only* be a "time" reference. It wouldn't be very idiomatic to convert it to a "sentence adverb" (by setting it off with commas) in your *exact* context, but *The ancient Britons, **before Caesar's invasion,** were ignorant pagans* is fine (syntactically, at least! :). But there are "spatial" (as opposed to "temporal") usages. At a pinch, *[Standing] before the king, John felt intimidated* could just about be transformed into *John, before the king, felt intimidated*.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for your comments. Got it! But my question though is whether a temporal PP can only modify time-related nouns.  You can say "I like the time before Christmas", but why does it sound strange when you say "I like the house before eviction".

Comment: @estudent I don't understand the sentence "I like the house before eviction". Sorry, but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @BillJ The sentence has the same structure as "I like the time before Christmas" but why do we have to say "I like the house in which I lived before I was evicted". I could have said "I liked the time I had before Christmas."

Comment: We  would more naturally say "I liked the house before I was evicted", where the expression "before I was evicted" is a temporal PP. It indicates when you liked the house.

Comment: @BillJ I guess my confusion is how do we know if a temporal PP is modifying the noun, or it is simply a subordinate clause. 

The sentence can have 2 meanings, right? You can interpret it as liking the house at the time prior to eviction, or the house you were living before being evicted.

Comment: A phrase cannot also be a clause. In "before I was evicted", "before" is a preposition with a clausal complement, thus it must be a preposition phrase. The PP simply expresses the fact that you liked the house at some time before you were evicted. The PP is an adjunct in clause structure, not a modifier in NP structure.